# xml syntax highlighting vim colorscheme fix

Tags: xml, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I started using the distinguished colorscheme (https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-distinguished/blob/develop/colors/distinguished.vim) and while the html syntax highlighting looks great the xml highlighting on the end tags doesn't match:
[Mismatched open and close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO0oP.png)

I've tried set syntax=html, but it still doesn't work correctly after the dot in the tags (e.g. the "dir" in `<endorsed.dir>` shows up blue instead of white). How can I fix the highlighting so that all the characters between the `</` and `>` are white? Ideally by editing `distinguished.vim`.

Answer (score 1):

You can "link" the `xmlEndTag` highlight group to the `xmlTag` highlight group:

```
hi link xmlEndTag xmlTag
```

Comment: It looks like my problem is actually with how it's doing the parsing of the xml.  I can get the entire open tag (including the &lt; and &gt>) to match the end tag using your method.  Probably need to learn to edit the syntax/xml.vim file if I really want to fix this.